# Main.cpp and a Function for Random number Generator C++

Tags: c++, random

Hi I'm a newbie up here and my hope to get it right rest here.
Last semester we dealt with Random number generator me and my friend we were able to come up with a simple program (below) which worked:

```
using namespace std;

int randomG() {
    int GER(0);
    GER=rand();
    GER %= 10;
    GER++;
    return(GER); 
}

int main() {
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i != 100; i++) {
        cout << randomG(); 
    }
}
```

Now this semester we got given this without going much into it. Basically he want us to To implement the random number generator with main.cpp that call a function FNC multiple times, to test the program we need to use state=1 as initial value. Call FNC from the main program. After 10000 calls: state should be equal to 399268537 (don't get what he mean here)

Below is our starting point:

```
double rand (void) {
    const long a=48271            //multiplier
    const long b=2147483647      //modulus
    const long c=b/a             //questient
    const long r=b % a           //remainder
    static long state =1;
    long t = a* (state % c) - r * (state/c);
    if(t >0)
        state=t;
    else
        state = t+b;
    return ((double) state / b);
}
```

for main.cpp we completely lost on what to do, we have no idea on how we going to call the function 
and coming up with a table from the program output for first 1 to 10 calls and  for 9991 to 10000 calls of FNG. we can't move any further. For sophomore like us, this is total confusion. any help will be apprecaited

```
int main() {
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int                        // we lost on what we should put in our main
```

After help from you guys Below is my codes but it still not compiling what am I missing here?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

double seed(long state) {
    g_state = state;
}

double rand(void) {
    const long a = 48271;
    const long b = 2147483647;
    const long c = b / a;
    const long r = b % a;
    long t = a* (g_state % c) - r * (g_state / c);
    if (t > 0)
        g_state = t;
    else
        g_state = t + b;
    return ((double)g_state / b);
}


int main() {
    std::vector<double> results;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; ++i) {
        double number = rand(); 
    if (i <= 10 || i >= 9991)
        results.push_back(number);
}
```

Comment: Go back to your professor and tell him his challenge makes no sense.

Comment: You're throwing around "FNC" and "FNG" without saying what you think they are... doesn't mean anything to me. Maybe check your lecture notes or textbook...? Anyway, if your "rand" function happens to be the "FNC" function, then what you're asked for is just std::vector<double> results; for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; ++i) { double sample = rand(); if (i <= 10 or i >= 9991) results.push_back(sample); }. (A vector is effectively a table).

Comment: yes FNC is just name: suppose to be "rand" function. [FNG was typo] Thanks for your input, starting to make sense to me now

Answer (score 1):

`state` is your seed here. You initialize it with 1. After 10000 calls it will be `399268537`. He gave you that value to check your implementation.

```
int main()
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
   {
      rand();
   }
}
```

If you call `rand()` again after this look and you step into the function and check the value of `state` you'll see it's 399268537.

Your code can me refactored as so that it looks much more like `srand()` and `rand()`:

```
double seed(long state)
{
   g_state = state;
}

double rand(void)
{
   const long a = 48271;            
   const long b = 2147483647;      
   const long c = b / a;           
   const long r = b % a;           
   long t = a* (g_state % c) - r * (g_state / c);
   if(t > 0)
      g_state = t;
   else
      g_state = t + b;
   return ((double)g_state / b);
}

int main()
{
   seed(1);
   for(int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
   {
      rand();
   }
}
```

Comment: You really shade light on my confusion. people like you make learning fun. I'm trying to rework the problem and see what I come up with. Thank you V. much, will return back to vote the answer

Comment: below is my code still not compiling
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

    double seed(long state)
    {
 S_state = state;
    }

    double rand(void)
    {
 const long a = 48271;
 const long b = 2147483647;
 const long c = b / a;
 const long r = b % a;
 long t = a* (S_state % c) - r * (S_state / c);
 if (t > 0)
  S_state = t;
 else
  S_state = t + b;
 return ((double)S_state / b);
    }

    int main() 
   {
 std::vector<double> results;
 for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; ++i) 
 { double sample = rand(); 
 if (i <= 10 || i >= 9991) results.push_back(sample);
 }